# Merge keys into same table

Tags: lua, lua-table

how would i merge the current perm and the new perm i add together to look like something like this {"key=69","key=360"} instead of just this 69 and then it replaces the current when new id added

```
tempkey = {}
    exports['ghmattimysql']:execute('SELECT * FROM user_properties WHERE house = @house AND number = @number', {['@house'] = house, ['@number'] = number}, function(rows)
        for k,v in pairs(rows) do
            if tonumber(v.perm) ~= nil then
                if tonumber(v.perm) < 0 then
                    tempkey[#tempkey+1] = {v.perm.. " " ..id}
                else
                    tempkey[#tempkey+1] = {id}
                end
            end
        end
        exports['ghmattimysql']:execute('UPDATE user_properties SET perm = @perm WHERE house = @house AND number = @number', {
            ['@house'] = house, 
            ['@number'] = number, 
            ['@perm'] = tempkey
        })
    end)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you are trying to do and there's little context for what the code does. Can you provide more context as to what you're trying to do? For example where you're getting `id` from? What should tempkey look like?

You're also using a table as an argument to that MySQL query, which I don't think is correct. I'm assuming this is query will only return one result?

At a guess, I think `perm` should be a string of numbers ("69 360"). If that is the case, you should be concatenating them into a string like this.

```lua
tempkey = ""
exports['ghmattimysql']:execute('SELECT * FROM user_properties WHERE house = @house AND number = @number', {['@house'] = house, ['@number'] = number}, function(rows)
    for k,v in pairs(rows) do
        if tonumber(v.perm) ~= nil then
            if tonumber(v.perm) < 0 then
                tempkey = v.perm .. " " .. id
            else
                tempkey = id
            end
        end
    end
    exports['ghmattimysql']:execute('UPDATE user_properties SET perm = @perm WHERE house = @house AND number = @number', {
        ['@house'] = house,
        ['@number'] = number,
        ['@perm'] = tempkey
    })
end)
```

Also, if you that query is only meant to return one result, you can do something like this instead to avoid unnecessarily iterating over the table `rows`

```lua
tempkey = ""
exports['ghmattimysql']:execute('SELECT * FROM user_properties WHERE house = @house AND number = @number', {['@house'] = house, ['@number'] = number}, function(rows)
    local data = rows[1]
    if tonumber(data.perm) ~= nil then
        if tonumber(data.perm) < 0 then
            tempkey = data.perm .. " " .. id
        else
            tempkey = id
        end
    end

    exports['ghmattimysql']:execute('UPDATE user_properties SET perm = @perm WHERE house = @house AND number = @number', {
        ['@house'] = house,
        ['@number'] = number,
        ['@perm'] = tempkey
    })
end)
```

Here it's being stored with a space character, but you could use a comma or anything. JSON is probably a bit too heavy for this purpose.